# Initialise inner nested function

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript function:

```js
var headerFunctionality = function () {
    var isInitialised = false;

    //other variables

    function init() {
        if (!this.isInitialised) {
            //do stuff here

            this.isInitialised = true;
        }
    };

    function destroy() {
        if (this.isInitialised) {
            //do stuff here

            this.isInitialised = false;
        }
    };
}
```

How do I change this so that I can call

```
headerFunctionality.init();
headerFunctionality.destroy();
```

I tried adding a return as follows:

```
return {
    init: init,
    destroy: destroy
}
```

but that only allowed me to call the `headerFunctionality()` and seem to then fire both inner functions.

Everything I have seen about this tells me that I need to do something like this:

```
function headerFunctionality() {
  ...same inner as above
}

var header = headerFunctionality();
header.init();
```

Is this the only way or am I able to change the above so the function is the variable itself?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want `isInitialised` for all the instances of objects created with `headerFunctionality`?

Comment: as written, your `return { .. }` should have worked fine - those inner functions would only get fired if you had called them explicitly (although you would have had to either explicitly call `headerFunctionality` to obtain that object, or wrap it in an IIFE)

Comment: @thefourtheye, I have a lot of variables I want to use within the scope of the function in both init and destroy and I only need one instance as this will be getting called on window resize

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? the question contains a clear problem that can be replicated by the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best, and most common, ways for you to achieve this is to use the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html). Wrap the `function` in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

```
var headerFunctionality = (function () {
    var isInitialised = false;

    //other variables

    function init() {
        if (!isInitialised) {
            //do stuff here

            isInitialized = true;
        }
    };

    function destroy() {
        if (isInitialised) {
            //do stuff here

            isInitialised = false;
        }
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        destroy: destroy
    }
})();
```

Comment: excellent thanks, so the iife was what I was missing - so simple when you know!

Comment: Oh yeah. I just copy/pasted your code. When using an IIFE, you don't need to use `this` inside that encapsulated function. I'll fix that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the function immediately:

```
var headerFunctionality = (function () {
    var isInitialised = false;  // I'm leaving it in, but it's not used anywhere! You change this.isInitiaized later which isn't the variable declared here.

    //other variables

    function init() {
        if (!this.isInitialised) {
            //do stuff here
            this.isInitialised = true;
        }
    };

    function destroy() {
        if (this.isInitialised) {
            //do stuff here
            this.isInitialised = false;
        }
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        destroy: destroy
    }

}());
```

You could also change the local `isInitialized` variable, not `this.isInitialized`:

```
var headerFunctionality = (function () {
    var isInitialised = false;  

    //other variables

    function init() {
        if (!isInitialised) {
            //do stuff here
            console.log( 'initialized' );
            isInitialised = true;
        }
    };

    function destroy() {
        if (isInitialised) {
            //do stuff here
            console.log( 'destroyed' );
            isInitialised = false;
        }
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        destroy: destroy
    }

}());
```

The diference between the second example and the first is that in the first (using `this`) the `isInitialized` property is exposed, sou you can check `headerFunctionality.isInitialized` from outside. In the second example the local variable kept in closure is modified and is not accessible from the external scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do something "Class-like" you can achieve your goal with something like this:

```
var HeaderFunctionality = function () {
    this.isInitialised = false;
    //other variables (with this)
}

HeaderFunctionality.prototype.init = function() {
    if (!this.isInitialised) {
        //do stuff here
        this.isInitialised = true;
    }
};

HeaderFunctionality.prototype.destroy = function() {
    if (this.isInitialised) {
        //do stuff here
        this.isInitialised = false;
    }
};
```

Then you can create and use a header functionality object as follows:

```
var hf = new HeaderFunctionality();
hf.init();
console.log(hf.isInitialized); // => true
hf.destroy();
console.log(hf.isInitialized); // => false
```